Best Lap Time Not Showing
I'm a Unity developer, and I've been having some trouble making the best lap counter for my boat racing game that I've been working on for the past year or so. Basically, when you finish a lap and cross the finish line, the best lap timer doesn't change. Yes, I've coded this timer into the script, but it refuses to work at all.
I've tried using the < and > symbols, but it didn't work. I've tried coroutines, but it still didn't work. I've even tried using the = symbol, but it still didn't work. So eventually, I gave up and decided to ask for help.
If any of you folks have a solution that might help solve this issue, then feel free to post them in the comment section down below, and I'll be more than happy to try them out to see if they will work. Anyway, have a nice day! Oh! And here's my code for those who are interested. 
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Race_Manager : MonoBehaviour {
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool enter = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isCalled = true;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool lapCompleted = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool raceStarted = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float currentHour;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float currentMinute;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float currentSecond;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float bestHour;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float bestMinute;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float bestSecond;
    public float timerSpeed = 10f;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int lapsDone;
    public int lapsToDo = 5;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int pointsHit;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Race_Checkpoint[] checkpoints;
    public Text currentTimeCounter;
    public Text bestTimeCounter;
    public Text lapCounter;
    public Canvas normalUI;
    public Canvas completionUI;
    public AudioSource successMusic;
    private bool raceOver = false;
    private CarCameras carCamera;
    private GameObject playerCar;
    private bool mainFunctionCalled = false;
    private bool timerActivated = false;
    private bool isFirstLap = true;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        playerCar = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");
        carCamera = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CarCameras> ();
        checkpoints = GetComponentsInChildren<Race_Checkpoint> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        lapCounter.text = string.Format("Laps: {0} / {1}", lapsDone, lapsToDo);
        currentTimeCounter.text = string.Format("Current Time: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", currentHour, currentMinute, currentSecond);
        bestTimeCounter.text = string.Format("Best Time: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", bestHour, bestMinute, bestSecond);
        if (raceOver == true && mainFunctionCalled == true) {
            StartCoroutine (WinFunction());
        }
        if (raceOver == true) {
            playerCar.GetComponent<CarController> ().handbrakeInput = 1f;
        }
        if (timerActivated == true) {
            currentSecond += Time.deltaTime * timerSpeed;
        }
        if (currentSecond > 60f)
        {
            currentSecond = 0f;
            currentMinute += 1f;
        }
        if (currentMinute == 60f) {
            currentHour += 1f;
            currentMinute = 0f;
        }
        if (enter == true) {
            foreach (Race_Checkpoint point in checkpoints)
                point.ResetPoint ();
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.tag == "Player" && raceStarted == false && lapsDone == 0 && isCalled == true) {
            timerActivated = true;
            raceStarted = true;
            lapsDone += 1;
            isCalled = false;
            enter = true;
        } else {
            enter = false;
        }
        if (other.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.tag == "Player" && raceStarted == true && isCalled == true && lapCompleted) {
            lapCompleted = false;
            isCalled = false;
            lapsDone += 1;
            pointsHit = 0;
            enter = true;
            StartCoroutine (TimerFunction ());
        } else {
            enter = false;
        }
        if (enter == true && lapsDone == lapsToDo + 1)
        {
            mainFunctionCalled = true;
            raceOver = true;
        }
        if (enter == true && lapsDone > 1f) {
            StartCoroutine (TimerFunction ());
        }
    }
    IEnumerator WinFunction() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0f);
        RestartGame restarter = GetComponent<RestartGame> ();
        successMusic.Play ();
        raceOver = true;
        normalUI.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        completionUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        playerCar.GetComponent<CarController> ().handbrakeInput = 1f;
        playerCar.GetComponent<CarController> ().throttleInput = 0f;
        playerCar.GetComponent<CarController> ().steerInput = 0f;
        playerCar.GetComponent<CarDynamics> ().controller = CarDynamics.Controller.external;
        carCamera.GetComponent<CarCameras> ().enabled = false;
        carCamera.GetComponent<CarCamerasController> ().enabled = false;
        carCamera.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("Camera_Finish");
        timerActivated = false;
        mainFunctionCalled = false;
        if (restarter != null) {
            restarter.enabled = false;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator TimerFunction()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0f);
        if (currentHour >= bestHour && isFirstLap && lapsDone <= 1f)
        {
            bestHour = currentHour;
        }
        if (currentMinute >= bestMinute && isFirstLap && lapsDone <= 1f)
        {
            bestMinute = currentMinute;
        }
        if (currentSecond >= bestSecond && isFirstLap && lapsDone <= 1f)
        {
            bestSecond = currentSecond;
        }
        if (currentHour <= bestHour && !isFirstLap && lapsDone > 1f)
        {
            bestHour = currentHour;
        }
        if (currentMinute <= bestMinute && !isFirstLap && lapsDone > 1f)
        {
            currentMinute = currentMinute;
        }
        if (currentSecond <= bestSecond && !isFirstLap && lapsDone > 1f)
        {
            bestSecond = currentSecond;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
        currentHour = 0f;
        currentMinute = 0f;
        currentSecond = 0f;
    }
}


id thor win a bunch of debug statements and find out what its doing.

Even though I'm certain that this won't do anything, I'm still going to try it out anyway because I just want to get this stubborn script out of my way.

Yep! Just as I thought, it didn't work. Well, I appreciate your help, though.

well, from this alone its hard to tell but if debugging doesnt show where your logic/code fails, then theres not enough debugging

Soooooo, your'e telling me I have to add more?

you need enough to find out whats going wrong, so as you cant tell yet, yes, you must need more

I'm genuinely sorry, I really don't understand what you're talking about!

if you cant see where your logic fails you need to show more information to yourself to show whats going on.. hence more debug..

I added some more debug statements and some more lines to the "TimerFunction" part of the script, and it appears that the script is trying to save all 3 of the floats twice.

Yay, you narrowed down the issue, thats a great start.. Next you need the debugs to find out why :)

Oh! that's what I could have done this whole time? I genuinely don't know what to say.

it may seem sarcastic, but often a lump of code is not enough to be sure about anything, learning to find out why its not doing what you want is a skill that will server you forever

Well, I guess that's a good thing to know. I'm gonna continue trying to fix the issues my script is giving me and I'll be back one I've fixed it. Talk to you soon! :)

part of me (like @giova-dev) would question the isFirstLap usage, as you do never set it to false,   id certainly argue about the logic in your timerfunction, as for example current = 2:59, vs best = 3:03, so sure, minutes is less so it now is 2:03 but 59 is not less than 03, so you now are stuck with 2:03 and that wasnt the laptime.

Alright, I’m back. But unfortunately, I haven’t made any further progress on the problem because I got sidetracked. And I’m feeling a bit guilty about it now because it shouldn’t take this long to find a solution for bugs like these. I’m sorry for making you guys wait this long, so I’m going to work on keeping my promises next time I ask for help with code problems. As soon as I get done doing homeschool, I’ll get straight to work and I’ll let you now if I’m finished. See you soon! (Hopefully)

Alright! I've made some changes to the script (mainly redoing the entire script from scratch, adding new lines of code and removing or reusing old bits of code) and it saves the time correctly now! However, it stops saving lap times after completing lap 2, sadly. I wonder what kind of solution you have for this problem.

Okay, I've added a WaitForSeconds function that automatically sets the isFirstLap setting to false after 0.2 seconds, and it works now!

In your code I can't find where you update the isFirstLap to false.
Probably you want to do it in the second if in OnTriggerEnter:
if (other.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.tag == "Player" &&
    raceStarted == true &&
    isCalled == true &&
    lapCompleted) {
    lapCompleted = false;
    isCalled = false;
    lapsDone += 1;
    pointsHit = 0;
    enter = true;
    isFirstLap = false; // update isFirstLap
    StartCoroutine(TimerFunction());
}


Okay, I've added some debug statements into the code and fixed the issue that you pointed out in your post, but it still won't work! I just don't get what I'm doing wrong!

Probably the error is in lapsDone, try initializing it to 0 in Start()

Well, if I understand this correctly, the lap counter is working fine, but the same can't be said for the best time/lap counter, BugFinder has just responded back to me after I told him about the changes to the script, so I'm gonna try and see what he wants me to do next. Although, I appreciate your advice.
